# Razor Redirect for Angular Partials

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, razor

What is the proper way to write code for Razor (ASP.NET Web Pages only, no MVC) to execute a redirect before the page is sent to Angular?

I have a collection of Angular partials in Razor where I simply want to check if the user is logged in. If they are logged in, then serve the page. If not, then Redirect to the Login partial.

Edit: My first attempt was to place `@{Reponse.Redirect("/myapp#/login");}` at the top of the page, but this just freezes up the page, likely because the redirect happens on the server but the URL format is for Angular on the client side.

Edit: My second attempt to redirect to the actual partial using `@{Reponse.Redirect("~/partials/login.cshtml");}` also freezes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying various methods of calling Response.Redirect has not worked. 
Instead, the solution that has worked was to use `@RenderPage` to render the login page instead of the actual content if the user is not logged in.

```
@if(notLoggedIn)
{
    @RenderPage("~/views/login.cshtml");
}

else
{
    <div id="regularPageContents">
         ....
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would add that code to the controller method responsible for handling the web request.  Also, check out `AuthorizeAttribute` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx))

I would suggest reading through one or more ASP.NET MVC 3+ tutorials.

Edit:

Ok then... still, read a [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/intro-to-web-pages-programming)

Add a @{ ... } block at the top of the page and put any code you want to run first in there.  The page executes in order.  Example:

```
@{
   var a = 1;
   var b = 2;
   var c = a + b;
}

...
<div>C is @c</div>
```

Comment: I'm not using MVC. I'm using Razor Web Pages as views for my Angular partials. http://www.asp.net/web-pages